# Tell difference in days and display to label swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I was wondering how to calculate the difference between two days and then display them to a label in Swift 4. And I don’t know why it’s not displaying anything. Here is the code I have so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
super.viewDidAppear(true)

var date = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “date”) ?? “”
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = “mm/dd/yyyy”
var todaysDate = Date()
var futureDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
var diffinDays = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: todaysDate, to: futureDate!)
self.label.text = “\(diffinDays)”
```

Please share any thoughts on what you think could be the problem. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Code still not working after the revisions and on top of that I could not print the var diffinDays. The only thing I can think of is that I am not technically running Swift 4 it is is running Swift 5 beta but most of the code runs over and there are not errors in the script. Here is the revised code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
super.viewDidAppear(true)

var date = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “date”) ?? “”
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = “MM/dd/yyyy”
var todaysDate = Date()
var futureDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
var diffinDays = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: todaysDate, to: futureDate!)
self.label.text = “\(String(describing: diffinDays.day))”
}
```

Comment: Look at the return result for [`Calendar#dateComponents(_from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293646-datecomponents?changes=latest_major) - it is returning a instance of [`DateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents?changes=latest_major)

Comment: Never use `String(describing:)` in user-facing text. — If you are just developing some code, why are you "printing" to a label? Just say `print` and read the console.

Comment: If your intention is to store a date in UserDefaults why are you not storing a date? It is beside the point to store a _string_ describing a date.

Comment: The date is getting set in another view controller. And I don’t just want to print out I want to display to a UILabel.

Answer (score 4):

Missed `.day` , You can try

```
self.label.text = "\(diffinDays.day)"
```

Comment: Even dow this is correct OP said it is not displaying anything. His string interpolation should display some info about the dateComponents. ie "isLeapMonth: false"

Comment: There is another error. The dateFormat "MM/dd/yyyy" OP is using `mm` (minutes) when he should be using `MM` for month

Comment: I see , OP should give feedback after fixing these issues

Comment: Thanks, I do not use this site often so just for my knowledge what does OP mean?

Comment: Also, how do you pop up the print window.

Comment: Tried all of suggestions but still blank and I can’t seem to get the print func to work even though it did earlier any more thoughts?

Comment: And how do I know if the func is even running